# Bluetooth problem, 20.10 on raspberry pi 4

Tags: bluetooth, raspberrypi, microsoft, 20.10, disconnect

Fresh install of 20.10 on a 8GB RPi4.
In bluetooth settings I can see my devices (MS BT mouse 3600 and MS Sculpt keyboard).
When I try to pair them, Ubuntu initiates the pairing process (code to type on the keyboard) but it fails and the devices show as not set up.
Then after a while they show as disconnected, and connection isn't possible.
I have tried to pair them via commandline, they quickly connect and disconnect.
Any Ideas?
TIA

Serge

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this fixed it :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:waveform/pi-bluetooth 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: That worked! Is this a bug with the distribution?

Comment: it seems so :
Here the bug fix : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1903048

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by upgrading to 21.04 hirsute hippo on my Pi 400 and activating the hirsute-proposed repositories.

But one problem remains: I can't get my jbl 650TBNC headset to be used as a headset with microphone. They just work as headphones., even when I wan't to change the setting to that function. Can anybody help?

Comment: Good job partially solving this. I suggest asking your follow-up question as a new question as the format of this site doesn't support answering answers. You can update your answer here when you get the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

On 22.04 you need to do an additional step to installing `pi-bluetooth`.  Disable the serial uart that interferes with the bluetooth interface.

Edit `/boot/firmware/config.txt` and set `enable_uart=0` or run `sudo pibootctl set serial.enabled=off`

For some reason 22.04 removes the `btcmd.txt` that's included in other distributions, so make sure your `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt` includes the following settings: `net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem using `Ubuntu MATE 22.04.4 LTS`, after an upgrade.
When listing bluetooth devices with `hcitool dev`, no device was found.

I tried all solutions above, but none of them worked. After some researchs, it seemed to due to an error during initilization of Bluetooth Modems with UART.

Indeed, I had this message when checking `sudo systemctl status hciuart.service` :

```
Job for hciuart.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status hciuart.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The solution for me was to add this command in `/boot/firmware/config.txt` :

`dtparam=krnbt`

According to [developer of the fix in the distro](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-bluetooth/issues/25#issuecomment-1426768853), gives the task of initialising the BT modem to the kernel.

After a reboot, `sudo systemctl status hciuart.service` specified that the configuration of Bluetooth Modems was successfully done !

Hope this helps